# Скрипт PHP на сайте не работает?

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование, telegram

Всех приветствую, написал сайт, чисто потестить, оформил скрипт вверху кода, что бы он отправлял сообщения в беседу телеграм через бота, о том, что пользователь зашёл на сайт/перешёл по ссылке, а он их не отправляет, при этом форма которую вы можете увидеть ниже, работает в совершенстве через тот же токен и чат айди, просто через отдельный .php как вы можете заметить. Хотел бы попросить о помощи, заранее благодарю)
p.s. Файл кода в формате .php.
upd Значения бот токен и чат айди ($to), были изменены, во избежание проблем.

```php
    <?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $BOT_TOOKEN = 'change';
    $to =  change;
    $message = 'that you need ';
    $parameters = array('chat_id' => $to, 'parse_mode' => 'HTML', "text" => $message);
    $url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . trim($BOT_TOOKEN) . '/sendMessage?' . http_build_query($parameters);
    $handle = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    $response = curl_exec($handle);

    ?>

    <html>
    <head>
        <title>vedrok</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form action="telegram.php" method="POST">
        
    <input type="tel" name="telephone"><br>
    <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    <input type="add" name="adress"><br>
    <input type="tel" name="number">
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Не обращайте внимания на то, что код при выполнении на странице отображается, если на хостинг загрузить только варнинги с 10 по 14 строку, видимо в этом проблема, помогите(

Comment: А эти предупреждения мы должны силой мысли узнавать или вы их всё же напишите?